# HTML/PHP Detectar se valor de formulário foi alterado

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário onde posso alterar coisas como `username`, `password`, `morada`, etc.
No site uso também uma sessão (login) para cada utilizador, a qual está definida pelo `username`.
O problema é que ao mudar o valor do formulário do `username` ele deixa de ser igual ao `username` da sessão atual, fazendo o login deixar de funcionar.
Existe algo que possa usar para detectar a mudança do `username`, para redirecionar para a página do login outra vez e mostrar um alerta dizendo "Username alterado, faça login novamente"?

Comment: Ao alterar o `username` podes alterar também o valor da sessão atual e assim já não perde a sessão.

Comment: Ou usa um JavaScript que detecte a mudança e já faça o redirecionamento em tempo real

Comment: Disponibilize algum trecho de código para embasamento para a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente no seu código há um botão para enviar a mudança no username, o que você pode fazer é: depois que a pagina que altera o username no banco de dados terminar, vc faz um redirect

```
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    print "<script>
    alert('username alterado bla bla')
location.href='página de login.php'
</script>";
```

location.href='página de login.php' > Essa parte que faz o redirecionamento

Answer (score -1):

Já que o nome de usuário pode ser alterado é recomendável então que você identifique a sessão pelo ID do usuário banco de dados, o que não geraria conflito caso o mesmo login estiver aberto em duas sessões diferentes, como o próprio nome diz, o ID é um mecanismo identificador. O usuário, e-mail, numero de documento, etc, por serem únicos também podem ser utilizados, mas não é recomendável caso esses valores possam ser alterados por causa de situações como essas.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode dar um session_start(); fazendo com que gere uma sessão única para cada navegador mesmo que usado pelo mesmo username em navegadores diferentes, cada um terá uma session diferente, o que você pode fazer é como eu faço nos meus aplicativos, você gera a session cada vez que o usuário entra no login e ao passar pelo verificador de senha, pega a session e poê dentro de um log de logins e caso desnecessário um log, altera o campo junto da tabela do usuário, ou seja, ao fazer login, você pode escolher

1) pega a session e poê em uma tabela de log de login com SESSION, DATA e USERNAME.

2) pega a session e altera a session do usuário dentro da própria tabela usuário.

e então quando ele fizer alteração de usuário, criar junto com isso uma session que indica ao navegador que isso aconteceu através da session armazenada no banco de dados, verifica então se são iguais, caso não, ele redireciona para login, caso queira mais detalhes, eu posso lhe mostrar um código prático.

Answer (score -1):

Sugiro a utilização de token:

Assim que o usuário fizer login, você gera o token e salva no BD e na sessão.

```
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

Ao fazer logoff você remove a token do BD e assim o usuario deve fazer login novamente.

Qualquer alteração no nome de usuário não afetará a token.

Espero ter ajudado.